# Can't find file Resource when filename contain with "#" using Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I found error when filename contain with "#".

Error:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: File does not exist.

But when filename without "#" still working.

```
String resource = "file:c:/Test#.txt";
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pathResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource[] resolveResources;
    try {
        resolveResources = pathResolver.getResources(resources);
        if(resolveResources.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("File does not exist: " + resources);
        }else{
            for (Resource resource : resolveResources) {
                if(!resource.exists()){ //true
                    throw new IllegalStateException("File does not exist: " + resource);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("File does not exist: " + resources);
    }
```

Comment: What would `resource.replace("#", "%23")` do? '#' ´has only meaning in an URL, as anchor, not URI. Try `"file:/c:/..."` too.

Comment: Thank you!! Joop Eggen. It's working!

Comment: Which of both? My guess `"file:/c:/..."`

Comment: resource.replace("#", "%23") is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file names validity depends on operating system (the file system to be more accurate), so to make sure that the file can be read on any Operating system; use alphanumeric and the underscore[Characters to avoid](http://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/digital/writing/characters-avoid/)

in your program the problem is in the URI making function

```
public static void main(String[] args ){   


    File f = new File("ahh#.txt");    

try {
    if(f.createNewFile()){
        System.out.println("ok"+ f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
   // file with string path 
   FileInputStream fis0;
    try {
        fis0 = new FileInputStream(
                new File(f.getAbsolutePath()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("file not found with string");
    }

    try {
        try {
            // file with URI
            FileInputStream fis1 =
                    new FileInputStream(
                            new File(
                                    new URI(f.getAbsolutePath())));
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            System.out.println("URI???");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("file not found with URI");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack but I think you need something like this :

```
@Test
public void test1() {

try {
    String resource = "file:c:\\tmp\\Test\u0023.txt";

    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pathResolver = new TestPathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource[] resolveResources;
    resolveResources = pathResolver.getResources(resource);
    if (resolveResources.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("File does not exist: " + resource);
    } else {
        for (Resource resource2 : resolveResources) {
            if (!resource2.exists()) { // true
                throw new IllegalStateException("File does not exist: " + resource2);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    fail();
}
```

}

Then you need to add modify the PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver

```
public class TestPathMatchingResourcePatternResolver extends PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver {

    public TestPathMatchingResourcePatternResolver() {
        super(new TestDefaultResourceLoader());
    }
}
```

Then you need to modify the DefaultResourceLoader

```
public class TestDefaultResourceLoader extends DefaultResourceLoader {
    @Override
    public Resource getResource(String location) {
        Assert.notNull(location, "Location must not be null");
        if (location.startsWith("/")) {
            return getResourceByPath(location);
        } else if (location.startsWith(CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX)) {
            return new ClassPathResource(location.substring(CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX.length()), getClassLoader());
        } else {
            try {
                // Try to parse the location as a URL...
                URL url = new URL(location);
                return new TestUrlResource(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                // No URL -> resolve as resource path.
                return getResourceByPath(location);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to modify the UrlResource

```
public class TestUrlResource extends UrlResource {

    public TestUrlResource(URL url) {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public File getFile() throws IOException {
        return new File(getURL().toString().replace("file:", ""));
    }
}
```